# Loop over associative arrays by substring

Tags: bash, array

In the following code, I create some associative arrays in a loop. The consist of two strings, a string identifier and a year. After creation, I want to access the arrays in a loop based on the identifier only.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare associative arrays of journal-year combinations
A_JOURNAL_LIST={JF,JFE,RFS}
B_JOURNAL_LIST={JBF,JFI,JMCB}
ALL_JOURNAL_LIST={JF,JFE,RFS,JBF,JFI,JMCB}
for year in {1998..2000} {2009..2011}
do
  eval "A_$year=($A_JOURNAL_LIST-$year) ;"
  eval "B_$year=($B_JOURNAL_LIST-$year) ;"
  eval "all_$year=($ALL_JOURNAL_LIST-$year) ;"
done
```

Here I easily get bunch of arrays of the form `A_1999` which e.g. expands to `JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999` and so on.

```
for journal in A B all
do
  echo "${'$journal'_1999[@]}"
done
```

I expect

```
JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999
JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
```

I got a `bad substitution error` all the time and I tried a lot of combinations. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) will be helpful here:

```
for journal in A B all
do
    indirect="${journal}_1999[@]"
    echo "$journal: ${!indirect}"
done
```

outputs

```
A: JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999
B: JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
all: JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
```

---

An eval-free rewrite. Arrays of arrays is not something bash is natively suited for, so I have to use space-separated strings and temp storage

```
# Declare associative arrays of journal-year combinations
a_journal_list=( {JF,JFE,RFS} )
b_journal_list=( {JBF,JFI,JMCB} )
all_journal_list=( "${a_journal_list[@]}" "${b_journal_list[@]}" )
declare -a a b all

for year in {1998..2000} {2009..2011}
do
    # store year-specific values as space-separated strings
    a[$year]=$( printf "%s-$year " "${a_journal_list[@]}" )
    b[$year]=$( printf "%s-$year " "${b_journal_list[@]}" )
    all[$year]=$( printf "%s-$year " "${all_journal_list[@]}" )
done  

selected_years=( 1998 1999 2000 )
for journal in a b all
do
    # I'll use the positional params for temp storage of the accumulated array
    set --
    for year in "${selected_years[@]}"
    do
        indirect="${journal}[$year]"
        # variable is unquoted to allow word splitting
        set -- "$@" ${!indirect}
    done
    echo $journal
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
done
```

Comment: That's an almost better way (one outside of the `eval` hell). How can I make `indirect` consist of more then one year? E.g. `indirect="${journal}_1998[@] ${journal}_1999[@] ${journal}_2000[@]"`?

Comment: You cannot, but I've posted an alternative

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to `eval` **hell**! Once you start using it, you never get rid of it.

```
for journal in A B all
do
  eval "echo \"\${${journal}_1999[@]}\""
done
```

There might be a much better way to do it, but I never bother with associative or otherwise nested arrays in shell scripts. If you need such data structures, you might be better off with a scripting language that supports them natively.

Actually, bash has support for associative arrays after a fashion. Whether they can be useful to you is another question, it's not portable to other shells in any case.

Comment: Good suggestion to look for another language: pick the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some misunderstood bash' arrays:

> Arrays
>
> ```
>    Bash provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables.  Any variable may be used as  an
>    indexed  array; the declare builtin will explicitly declare an array.  There is no maximum limit on the
>    size of an array, nor any requirement that members be indexed or assigned contiguously.  Indexed arrays
>    are  referenced  using  integers  (including  arithmetic  expressions)  and are zero-based; associative
>    arrays are referenced using arbitrary strings.  Unless otherwise noted, indexed array indices  must  be
>    non-negative integers.
>
>    An  indexed  array  is  created automatically if any variable is assigned to using the syntax name[sub‐
>    script]=value.  The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate  to  a  number.
>    To  explicitly  declare  an  indexed  array,  use  declare  -a name (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
>    declare -a name[subscript] is also accepted; the subscript is ignored.
>
>    Associative arrays are created using declare -A name.
>
>    Attributes may be specified for an array variable  using  the  declare  and  readonly  builtins.   Each
>    attribute applies to all members of an array.
>
>    Arrays  are  assigned  to  using  compound assignments of the form name=(value1 ... valuen), where each
>    value is of the form [subscript]=string.  Indexed array assignments do not require anything but string.
>    When  assigning  to  indexed arrays, if the optional brackets and subscript are supplied, that index is
>    assigned to; otherwise the index of the element assigned is the last index assigned to by the statement
>    plus one.  Indexing starts at zero.
>
>    When assigning to an associative array, the subscript is required.
>
>    This  syntax  is  also  accepted  by the declare builtin.  Individual array elements may be assigned to
>    using the name[subscript]=value syntax introduced above.  When assigning to an indexed array,  if  name
>    is  subscripted  by  a  negative number, that number is interpreted as relative to one greater than the
>    maximum index of name, so negative indices count back from the end of the array, and  an  index  of  -1
>    references the last element.
> ```